# Cannot reach edittext from one fragment via FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments

Not sure how to state this correctly. I have class

```
TabsFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    FragmentTabHost.OnTabChangeListener, OnClickListener
```

Now on the first tab

```
StartFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
```

I have a button which opens

```
WinnersFragment extends ListFragment
```

by

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("WINNERS_FRAGMENT");
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.tabhost, fragment2);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now on this Winners fragment I have a button and an edittext.  I reach the button in my TabsFragmentActivity and it fires fine.  However I cannot seem to reach my edittext.  So in my TabsFragmentActivity I have

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.ibSearch:

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textenter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.winners_list, null);
    final EditText userinput = (EditText) textenter
                .findViewById(R.id.etSearchState);

    String searchState = userinput.getText().toString();
    System.out.print("The input is: "+searchState);          
    fragment2.InitTask(searchState);
    if (userinput.length() > 0) {
    userinput.getText().clear();
    }
    break;  

}
}
```

where WinnersFragment fragment2 = new WinnersFragment();
The fragment2.InitTask(searchState);  fires but searchState is null.

I believe my issue is here but I cannot figure it out.  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textenter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.winners_list, null);

Comment: you cannot do like. use a interface as a call back to the activity first and then pass the value to `framgent2`. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `final View textenter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.winners_list, null);` you create new View and never add it to any container in view hierarchy. You should implement `onCreateView()` in your `WinnersFragment`, inflate your layout there and return it. After that, this `View` will be assigned to `WinnersFragment` and you can find your `EditText` by, for example, `fragment2.getView().findViewById(R.id.etSearchState);`